# C++ Read in data types string, int double from a file. Put each line of data into a vector of objects

Tags: c++, object, vector

```
data file:

candy, 1.99, 26
chips, 2.55, 22

 //my attempt to read in each line creating a new object for the line

while (getline(inFile, line, '\n')) {

        istringstream ss(line);
        ss >> name >> price >> amount;

        products newProduct(name, price, amount);  
        item.push_back(newProduct);
    }
```

Right now I am only getting the name and price of only the first line.

How can I read in the entire line storing all three values  for all lines in the file?

Comment: I have variables `string line; string name; double price; int amount; vector<products>item;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got to handle comma after price:

```
char comma;
ss >> name >> price >> comma >> amount;
```

Just to clarify: the name is read with the first comma. Then the stream reads a double - finds a comma and stops here. Then you request to read an int but all it got is... a comma. You need to get rid of it to proceed.

Update:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream file("xxx, 23.0, 11\nyyy, 99.3, 100");
    while (!file.eof()) {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(file, line);
        std::istringstream line_stream(line);

        std::string name;
        double price;
        char comma;
        int amount;
        line_stream >> name >> price >> comma >> amount;
        std::cout << "name: " << name << std::endl;
        std::cout << "price: " << price << std::endl;
        std::cout << "amount: " << amount << std::endl;
        std::cout << "===================" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for the first line. I am still not getting any of the data after the first line. After the  first line of data is processed the loop is terminating. I changed the condition of the loop to `!inFile.eof()` and moved the `getline(inFile, line, '\n')` into the loop itself and that did not seem to change anything.

Comment: @AlexGessinger See for the update. It works as expected. File is simulated as stringstream but if you change it to input file stream then should be what you need

Answer (score 0):

Try to structure the code like this:

```
if( inFile.is_open() ){
  string line;
  while(getline(inFile, line){
    ...
  }
}
```